# Why nvl doesn't work inside concat function in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using a query to select all columns of a table and separate them by a comma(',') but in case if value of a column is null then I'll use string 'null' in place of a value.

The query I am trying is -

```
SELECT CONCAT(NVL(ID,'null'),',',NVL(NAME,'null'),',',NVL(ROLL_NO,'null')) 
FROM DUAL
```

```
Expected result-
1,john,123
2,josh,null
```

I intend to run this query on a spark temporary table. But before that I tried running it on sql developer.
But I'm getting ORA-00909 : invalid number of arguments error. I can't find where I'm going wrong here.

Extra question (not necessary to answer) : Is there a way to concatenate all columns by not writing columns manually? I know there is a function concat_ws in spark.sql and oracle, where we can use a delimiter but it also neglects null value instead of replacing them with 'null' string but again I've to write all columns manually even in concat_ws.

Comment: There are very likely two errors in the code. The first one has already been pointed out in the first Answer: `concat` only accepts two arguments. After you fix that, though (as shown in that answer), you will get one more error, **if** column `id` or column `roll_no` (or both) is or are numeric data type. That's because `nvl` must return the same data type in all cases; it can't return either a number or the string `'null'`. To fix this other mistake, you will need to wrap the numeric columns within `to_char()` first, and only then apply `nvl` to the result.

Comment: According to your description, the main problem is not the incorrect usage of CONCAT (although you accepted this as correct answer), but different datatypes. The advantage of COALESCE or NVL is to simply replace null values as long as the data types match. Since this is not the case here, I wouldn't use them at all, but just use case when.

Comment: The error mentioned is about the CONCAT function. A simplified version throws the same ORA-00909 error: `select concat('a', 'b', 'c') from dual`. But you're right that, after solving that, there are more issues with the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle's CONCAT function accepts only 2 arguments.

But there is the concat operator, `||`, which does what you want:

```
SELECT NVL(ID,'null') || ',' || NVL(NAME,'null') || ',' || NVL(ROLL_NO,'null') 
FROM DUAL
```

Comment: `concat` is a SQL Standard function (`nvl` is an example of an "Oracle" function).

Comment: @mathguy Standard or not, the point is that Oracle's implementation of the `CONCAT` function accepts only 2 arguments, while in some other databases like MySQL, it accepts more. Because of that, OP's query would work (or at least not fail with _this_ error) on MySQL, but not in Oracle.

Comment: And indeed, `coalesce` could be used as a SQL standard replacement for `nvl`.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know I was missing such a basic point about concat diff in oracle and mysql. Thank you. Also I changed nvl to coalesce because It was throwing error same as what @mathguy mentioned. Thanks for pointing out that.

Comment: COALESCE will throw the same error. The advantage of COALESCE is that it's working on each DB, not Oracle DB only, but it also requires matching data types. This is no good use case for those functions. It's kind of overhead to use both TO_CHAR and COALESCE, that's why a case when construct becomes a good alternative.

Comment: Thanks @JonasMetzler I will have to replace it with case when construct. Thought not to use it in case there are hundreds of columns but I think case-when is best to use here

Comment: What you are doing there is overall no good idea. Both using a case when construct or using to_char and coalesce will get more and more unpleasant the more columns you take for that. This kind of data manipulation should generally be avoided. Depending on your use case, you should either define a default value for your columns or handle this afterwards in another application.